# What are the options for editing a date in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

There doesn't appear to be a date-picker with the current beta Windows Phone 7 SDK.  What are the options available?  Will there be a date control when the final SDK comes out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been frequently requested since mix in the wp7 forums and recently confirmed as shipping in the **Mobile Controls Toolkit** soon along with other popular controls that haven't made it into the SDK.

Date as yet not announced, though it can't be long now.

SDK RTM last target commented as end of month a while back, we'll see how the team is going soon.

**EDIT:** For reference, [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Jaime+Rodriguez/Windows-Phone-Design-Days-Applications/Default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) is where you can find Jaimer's confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of rumours that one might be made available with the RTM version of the tools but nothing official. It's a control that a lot of people have been asking for so hopefully one will be made available at or shortly after RTM.

For now you'll have to roll your own.

As a pointer in the right direction, Nick Randolph has created a wheel control which may be of use: http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2010/08/16/Windows-Phone7-Wheel-Control-e28093-Updated.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've heard there will be a date picker with RTM, however in the mean time I've build a decent replacement that works for my application.

In my app, the user really only needs to select the date within about +/- 30 days or so, so I just combined a slider (with today's date being the middle of the slider) and a textblock.